# Parameter count mismatch - due to babel polyfill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill

To support IE11, I had to add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.min.js"></script>`
to my .aspx file.

But this throws this error in console.

`Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.`

How can I solve this error without removing Babel-polyfill script?

If I don't add that script for babel-polyfill, the error is not thrown.

```
Warning Error: 
Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (http://.../ScriptResource.axd?d=D9...:237:15)
    at Function.Error$parameterCount [as parameterCount] (http://.../ScriptResource.axd?d=D9...:413:21)
    at Function$_validateParameterCount [as _validateParameterCount] (http://.../ScriptResource.axd?d=D9...:118:23)
    at Function$_validateParams [as _validateParams] (https://.../ScriptResource.axd?d=D9...:70:18)
    at String$startsWith (http://.../ScriptResource.axd?d=D9...:491:22)
    at String.startsWith (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.min.js:1:81150)
    at new Sys$UI$DomEvent (http://...:3986:16)
    at browserHandler (http://...:4052:42)
```

Comment: I got the same error (in Polish language though) I didn't solve it yet but to contribute to the issue I did some tests and it seems that a **publish release build of webforms application** works well.

But boy do I need it working on local machine to develop things! Waiting for any help guys maybe @microsoft should look at this issue ?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC2jJ.png

Answer (score 5):

Try to add ScriptMode="Release" to the ScriptManager.
Look at ZariffS reply for similiar problem https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4599#issuecomment-343506686

Comment: OMG! Works flawlessly! That would be an answer why it works with published version of application :)

Comment: I just opened an old webforms app for some updates, and got this error.  Thanks for the solution.  Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to not use babel-polyfill and use `core-js` with `regenerator-runtime` instead.

According to official docs, babel-polyfill has been deprecated

> As of Babel 7.4.0, this package has been deprecated in favor of directly including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime (needed to use transpiled generator functions):

And a preferred way to polyfill browser functions is to include packages `regenenerator-runtime` and `core-js` which you can find on https://www.npmjs.com/ and then include them at the entrypoint of your react/angular/etc. project

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime

https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js